# Can't delete "Application Data" folder after copying AppData directory

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions

I wanted to move the `AppData` folder in my Windows 10 user's home directory to another disk, so I copied that folder via the `robocopy` tool. That whole operation failed at some point so I decided to give it up. Then I wanted to delete the new `AppData` directory on the (new) target destination, but that did not work - "permission denied".

It turned out that "Application Data" folder under `AppData/Local` is a symlink, not a real folder, so it seems `robocopy` messed that up, I ended with `Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/...`

Now I can't take ownership of that whole folder structure, I can't delete it from the Windows Explorer, I can't delete it from an elevated command line, etc. How can i delete that newly copied `Application Data` folder/symlink?

Comment: Is your AppData folder working?  You should not move these individual folders within your main USER folder.

Comment: Yeah so that's why I stopped this experiment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for the records: I ended up booting from an Ubuntu Live CD, mounted the Windows disk and removed that new `Application Data` folder from there ...